# Simplifying javascript using for loop with update array values

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var thisdata = $.jStorage.get(something);
var nameChi = "nameChi" + i;
var name = "name" + i;
var brought = "brought" + i;
var amount = "amount" + i;
var np = "np" + i;
var num = "num" + i;
```

Above is working code which I want to simplify. I tried to turn individual assignments into a for loop with the code below:

```
thisdata = $.jStorage.get(something);
var generateid = ['thisdata', 'nameChi', 'name', 'brought', 'amount', 'np', 'num']

for (var a in generateid){
    var generateid[a] = generateid[a] + i
}
```

However, this is not working. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can't create dynamic variables like that. Just assign the values to another array

Comment: ^^ as said.. you can't create a dynamic variable but you can create a object with dynamic property. That is a close one to what you are trying

Comment: There's lots of things at play here - using a for-in to iterate over an array, using the `var` keyword when trying to mutate that array, and a possible misunderstanding of when to use Objects.

Comment: what do you do with the variables later on?

Comment: Thanks for you guys comments!! @JochenBedersdorfer , actually i am using a noob way to get data from a json file (let's say data A & data B), and I try to make those data (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3) viewable (bring them to front end).

Comment: @YuenKevin Are you trying to create an array of objects?

Comment: @RobG OP is trying to assign variable identifiers to elements of an existing array.

Comment: @guest271314 kind of, the array is created already, I'm trying to take that array(s) and display them into my own html file.

Comment: @YuenKevin Are you simultaneously trying to create a variable identifier for each of the elements of the array?

Comment: This is what you should consider doing :
https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/swb5vrnr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use destructuring assignment, `Array.prototype.map()`

```
var generated = ["nameChi", "name", "brought", "amount", "np", "num"]
                .map((n /*,i*/) => n + i);
var [nameChi, name, brought, amount, np, num] = generated;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var generateid = ['thisdata', 'nameChi', 'name', 'brought', 'amount', 'np', 'num']
generateid = generateid.map(each => each + i);
```

How does this work?

- `map` create a new array with the result of function
- `each => each + i` is an anonymous function that adds `i` to each element

Comment: Where does `i` come from?

Comment: Where ever it comes from in the example given in the question …

Comment: @akuhn Fair call :)

Comment: The OP wants to be able to generate variable names dynamically and not update his array values .. you can sense that intent of OP if you look at his code

Answer (score 0):

In your code the Index is the problem for the assignment, Use this following code for the usage,

```
var val;
var generateid = ['thisdata', 'nameChi', 'name', 'brought', 'amount', 'np', 'num'];
var index=0;
for (val of generateid ) {
    generateid [index]=val + "i"
}
```

How is works,

1. In every for loop index will be incremented, So you can find the insertion index using that index value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.

```
 var ids = ["thisdata", "nameChi", "name", "brought", "amount", "np", "num"];
 var generateid = {};
 for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){ 
      generateid[ids[i]] = ids[i] + i; 
 }
```